# 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, servlets, jetty

When I try to access a webapp remotely I get 401 errors, and a websocket connection I have does not work probably as a result of that. Using localhost works perfectly fine, but I can't seem to figure out for the life of me why it doesn't work. Any suggestions? As a reference point, this is a fairly untouched new install of Jetty 7.2.0.

Comment: are you using Local IP or External IP?

Comment: I'm trying to access it via an external IP address, localhost and 192.168... all work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my router, running Tomato, had port 8080 used for remote access. When trying to access the IP address locally it would already be used.